# certificatehostnamemismatch while installing google cloud SDK?

Tags: httplib2, google-cloud-sdk

I met a certificationhostnamemismatch error while installing google clould SDK. The error message looks like this:

`....
httplib2.certificatehostnamemismatch: server presented certificate that does not match host dl.google.com
....`

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I searched on the internet and found that might be several reasons:

1. the python version
2. the host file

I checked my environment and found that the host file was changed to access google websites for convenience. So I removed the host file. Now everyting works fine.